# WorkbookOpen function with an If statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that runs when i open a file that has something in its name and has a specific value in a cell(code below).

First of all, is it possible to use both these statements together? One that verifies a condition "while the file is opening" and a second that needs a open file to find its answer?

If not, what is the best way to do it?

When i use only the condition of the filename partially containing something, it works, but when i try to apply both conditions, it kind of ignores the second one (cell value).

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MonitorApp As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Set MonitorApp = Application

End Sub

Private Sub MonitorApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

    Dim Text As String
    Dim myCell As Range

    Set myCell = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    Text = "Partial Name of File"

    If UCase(Left(Wb.Name, Len(Text))) = UCase(Text) And myCell.Value <> "Example" Then

    'Code'

    End If
End Sub
```

I expect that the code should run only if both conditions are true, but the code is running even if `myCell.Value = "Example"`

Comment: Is `myCell` in `wb` or in `ThisWorkbook`? From your description, it sounds like it's actually in `wb`.

Comment: If the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, just give it a meaningful `(Name)` property (F4 to bring up the "properties" toolwindow), and then you can use that name in-code - eg. if the `(Name)` is `Sheet1` then you can do `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 42`; if `(Name)` is `MyAwesomeSheet` then you can do `MyAwesomeSheet.Range("A1").Value = 42`, and never need to dereference these objects from a `Worksheets` collection; you only ever need to do that when you work with sheets that are created at run-time, and/or sheets that aren't in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: I've tried this, works as expected. Make sure your cell has that exact value "Example" that your code compares to.

Comment: As pointed by @BigBen, i should have used Wb instead of ThisWorkbook when setting myCell, that did the trick